# Speed up the differental evolution algorithm with thousands of parameters

Tags: python, algorithm, differential-evolution

I am trying to make a lumped rainfall-runoff balance model with a lot parameters (from 37 to 1099) in python. As input it will receive daily rainfall and temperature data and then provides output as a daily flows.

I am stuck on the optimisation method for the model's calibration. I choosed differential evolution algorithm because it is easy to use and can be applied to this kind of problem. The algorithm I wrote works well and it seems to minimise the objective function (which is Nash-Sutcliff model Eficiency - NSE). The problem starts with higher number of parameters which significantly slows the whole algorithm.
The DE algorithm I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import flow    # a python file from where I get observed daily flows as a np.array

def differential_evolution(func, bounds, popsize=10, mutate=0.8, CR=0.85, maxiter=50): 

    #--- INITIALIZE THE FIRST POPULATION WITHIN THE BOUNDS-------------------+

    bounds = [(0, 250)] * 1 + [(0, 5)] * 366 + [(0, 2)] * 366 + [(0, 100)] * 366
    dim = len(bounds)
    pop_norm = np.random.rand(popsize, dim)
    min_bound, max_bound = np.asarray(bounds).T
    difference = np.fabs(min_bound - max_bound)
    population = min_bound + pop_norm * difference

    # Computed value of objective function for intial population

    fitness = np.asarray([func(x, flow.l_flow) for x in population])
    best_idx = np.argmin(fitness)
    best = population[best_idx]  

    #--- MUTATION -----------------------------------------------------------+
    
    # This is the part which take to much time to complete
    for i in range(maxiter):
        print('Generation: ', i)
        for j in range(popsize):

            # Random selection of three individuals to make a noice vector
            idxs = list(range(0, popsize))    
            idxs.remove(j)              
            x_1, x_2, x_3 = pop_norm[np.random.choice(idxs, 3, replace=True)]
            noice_vector = np.clip(x_1 + mutate * (x_2 - x_3), 0, 1) 

    #--- RECOMBINATION ------------------------------------------------------+  

            cross_points = np.random.rand(dim) < CR
            if not np.any(cross_points):
                cross_points[np.random.randint(0, dim)] = True

            trial_vector_norm = np.where(cross_points, noice_vector, pop_norm[j])
            trial_vector = min_bound + trial_vector_norm * difference
            crit = func(trial_vector, flow.l_flow)
            
            # Check for better fitness of objective function
            if crit < fitness[j]:
                fitness[j] = crit
                pop_norm[j] = trial_vector_norm
                if crit < fitness[best_idx]:
                    best_idx = j
                    best = trial_vector
    return best, fitness[best_idx]
```

The rainfall-runoff model itself is a function which works basically on lists and via for loop it iteraters over each row to compute daily flows by simple equation.
The objective function NSE is vectorised by numpy arrays:

```
import model # a python file where rainfall-runoff model function is defined 

def nse_min(parameters, observations):
    
    # Modeled flows from model function
    Q_modeled = np.array(model.model(parameters))

    # Computation of the NSE fraction
    numerator = np.subtract(observations, Q_modeled) ** 2
    denominator = np.subtract(observations, np.sum(observations)/len(observations)) ** 2
    return np.sum(numerator) / np.sum(denominator)
```

Is there any chance to speed it up? I found out about the numba library which "compiles python code to a machine code" and then let you compute on CPU more efficiently or on GPU using CUDA cores. But I do not study anything related to IT and have no idea how CPU/GPU works, therefore I do not know how to use numba properly. Can anyone help me with it? Or can anyone suggest different optimisation method?

What I use:
Python 3.7.0 64-bit,
Windows 10 Home x64,
Intel Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80 Ghz,
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB GDDR5,
16 GB RAM DDR4.

I am a python beginner who study a water management and use python sometimes just for some sripts which make my life easier in data processing. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the interesting question. Could you provide an example of calling the function or better yet a minimal reproducible example please? The parameters are a bit unclear to me - especially the func bounds one.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I edited the parameters, there was a misspell. It should go as "def differential_evolution(func, bounds, popsize=10, mutate=0.8, CR=0.85, maxiter=50)" where func is objective function (nse_min), bounds are interval limits for model parameters. Since I defined bounds inside the function then function call would look like this: calibrated_parameters, calibrated_nse = differential_evolution(nse_min).

Comment: Where do you import flow from please?

Comment: flow.py is a file in my same workspace as DE algorithm. Flow.py contains a functions to process input data of observed flows and it returns a 1D numpy array of daily flows to which I want to be as close as possible with flows from model with optimalised parameters.

Comment: It is kind of hard to try to tune your code when it's incomplete. I would like to profile it etc. to take a look at the bottlenecks.

Comment: I can compile my whole work folder and provide it to you. I would really appreciate some help with this problem. Also I see you are from Prague so we can even discuss it in the czech language. Shall we do it this way?

Comment: Yes. If you could set up a git repository it would be nice. I don't mind using czech, however SO isn't a site for that :-).

Comment: Ok, I do not know what git repository is and how it works. So after I learn about it and hopefully set it up I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Shamis, I created a private repository on GitHub. Can I add you as a collaborator so you can see/edit the code there?

Comment: Sure, please do :-). My github acc is SimaTian.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python library multiprocessing. It just makes more processes to run your function.
you can use it like this.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: If I applied this exact use from of "Process", my code did not run faster. I am not sure if those for loops in my DEA function can be parallelised that simply.

Comment: you could use the library threading instead. I used it with one of my projects and it made it work way faster and smoother.

Example:
import threading

def f(name):
      print('hello ', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      x = threading.Thread(target = f())
      x.start

Comment: the example is in a comment so it will be hard to understand. try copy and pasting it to your IDE